# qgis plugin: "WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid"

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

OS: Windows 7 64bit

GIS: QGIS 1.8  (qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-1.8.0-2-Setup.exe)

path variable:

```
GISBASE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\lib

PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\msys\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27;

PYTHONLIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python
GRASS_SH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe
```

---

---

I have created a plugin for QGIS, with the QGIS plugin builder.
Now i would like to import grass.script into this script

```py
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources_rc

# Import the code for the dialog
from testdialog import testDialog

# Import grass.script
import os, sys
import grass.script as grass
```

If i run this Script then i get the following error:
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid

The whole Error massage is:

```
Couldn't load plugin test due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 164, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/admin/.qgis//python/plugins\test\__init__.py", line 52, in classFactory
    from test import test
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/admin/.qgis//python/plugins\test\test.py", line 31, in 
    import grass.script as grass
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from core  import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 1201, in 
    debug_level = int(gisenv().get('DEBUG', 0))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 558, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 238, in read_command
    ps = pipe_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 215, in pipe_command
    return start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 177, in start_command
    return Popen(args, **popts)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 56, in __init__
    startupinfo, creationflags)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 784, in _get_handles
    p2cread = self._make_inheritable(p2cread)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 823, in _make_inheritable
    _subprocess.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, f440b60

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/admin/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/admin/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\grass\\grass-6.4.3RC2\\etc\\python', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
```

Has someone an idea ?

regards Marcus

Answer (score 1):

I solved some problems with Popen in Windows reading the doc [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) 
and [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/).

Maybe invoke shell=True, can help.

Comment: I kwon it is a two year old answer, but.. I have the same problem now, can you elaborate how you solved the problem? Thanks